# DRY Docker compose services: reference service name inside service defition

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have a docker-compose file that has many similar services. Each service has a name and several settings that contain/are equivalent to that same name. I would like to avoid having to repeat the service name several times as that's prone to copy-paste errors.

Here is what my docker-compose file looks like (abbreviated):

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  my_first_service:
    image: some-image
    container_name: my_first_service
    environment:
      - ROS_HOSTNAME=my_first_service
    logging:
      driver: ${LOGGING_DRIVER}
      options:
        tag: "my_first_service"
    command: rosrun my_first_service my_first_service_node
    restart: ${RESTART_POLICY}

  my_second_service:
    image: some-image
    container_name: my_second_service
    environment:
      - ROS_HOSTNAME=my_second_service
    logging:
      driver: ${LOGGING_DRIVER}
      options:
        tag: "my_second_service"
    command: rosrun my_second_service my_second_service_node
    restart: ${RESTART_POLICY}

  ... (repeats ~20 more times)
```

I know that I can use YAML anchors and aliases to avoid having to repeat the common parts of each service (like `image`, `logging.driver`, `restart` in the above example).

But what I really (or rather, additionally) want to avoid, is having to write `my_first_service` 6 times. I might be able to get around it in the `command` by checking e.g. the containers hostname in a launch script, but for the other four times, I have no idea.

Ideally I would be able to reference the service name (the YAML key inside the `services` map), something like

```
services:
  my_first_service:
    image: some-image
    container_name: ${parent.key}
    environment:
      - ROS_HOSTNAME=${parent.key}
    logging:
      driver: ${LOGGING_DRIVER}
      options:
        tag: "${parent.key}"
    command: rosrun ${parent.key} ${parent.key}_node
    restart: ${RESTART_POLICY}
```

but as far as I can tell, YAML does not support anything like that.

Is there any way I can achieve this? How can I write my docker-compose file as DRY as possible?

Comment: Can you set up your application to get the metadata it needs from the hostname (as in the `hostname` shell command)?  Setting `container_name:` or `hostname:` will set that, within the container, and then you wouldn't need to repeat it in the environment or the command line; and you should be able to configure the logging system to "find" the container name as well.

Comment: (If this were Kubernetes, I'd tell you to use Helm chart templating, but that's a pretty complex infrastructure.  Still, if you have 20+ containers to manage, it might be right.)

Comment: I'll look into Kubernetes / Helm chart templating, thanks. You're right, I could get around the repetition for the logging.options.tag according to [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/log_tags/). Similar with the env variables, which I could set in my entry point script. Really the main one to solve is `container_name: ${parent.key}`

Comment: On its own Compose will set the container name to `PROJECT_SERVICE_1`, where `PROJECT` defaults to the current directory name and `SERVICE` is the name of the service block.  If you needed to, that name could be used as a host name for inter-container networking (it wouldn't be the primary name if you were configuring things manually).

Comment: I might be able to live with `PROJECT_SERVICE_1`. `that name could be used as a host name` how would I go about doing that?

Comment: "wouldn't be the primary name if you were configuring things manually"
I'm not sure what you mean by that